# Can't read my csv file in jupyter - kubernetes

Tags: python, pandas, kubernetes, jupyter

I recenlty deployed jupyter into kubernetes, and now i want to read my data and make the data cleaning, while i'm runing :

```
data = pd.read_csv("home/ghofrane21/data/Les indices des prix.csv", header=None)
```

I get this error :

**File Not Found Error [Errno2] File home/ghofrane21/data/Les indices des prix.csv does not exist**

The file already exist :
[image]

Comment: Try checking your current working directory from the notebook with os.getcwd().

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob i get home/joviyan

Comment: Probably [jovyan](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/what-is-with-the-weird-jovyan-user/1673?u=fomightez)?  If you open a terminal from inside Jupyter, can you check the navigate to the CSV file & permissions for your CSV with something like `ls -lah`?